# AndroidStudio get more and more dark grey bars when opening dialogs

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

[image: Text]
AndroidStudio(Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1) get more and more dark grey bars when opening dialogs. When I open a dialog, something wrong happened that a grey bar appears. Grey bars have no response to click. Restart AndroidStudio can work, but this bothers me when I focus on work, I have to stop working to restart it. Updating to newest version of AndroidStudio can not work. What can I do to remove all these bars?

Log file link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vdjrjm8mn717hbd/idea.log?dl=0

Comment: Hello! Do you have any custom plugins installed?

Comment: There are no installed plugins recently

Comment: Do you face it with any dialog? Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Comment: Its show usages of method dialog. Log file uploaded. @y.bedrov

Comment: Please try to use newer Android Studio version.

Comment: Ohh. Updating to Android Studio Chipmunk, everything is okay.